# Segues Programmatically Pattern

Tags: ios, events, model-view-controller, controller

Does anybody know if there is a certain pattern for handling segues programmatically in a MVC way?
I would think the best way would be to work with an event system within a controller.
I want that all the view controllers connect to this navigationController instead of handling all the logic within the viewController logic itself. I want to out source this logic

Comment: navigationController.pushViewController and navigationController.popViewController?

Comment: Hi Reinier. Of course I know this function... but its just not mvc safe... as VC1 has to know about VC2. 

Really there should be a call to an action.. like "leave screen".. the controller (navigationController) then should deal with the logic... instead of the vc.

Comment: So thats why I ask for a pattern.
Also how to deal with overlay menus and stuff... Crazy to define them all the time in every vc or in the app delegate.

There should be a class that deals with that logic. A controller.

Answer (score 0):

In most of your view controllers, you will have access to a `prepareForSegue` function, with one parameter called `sender`.

If you kick off a segue programatically with `performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueID", sender: yourVC)` then this function will be called, and you'll be able to pass information from the sender to the new view controller.

In this function, to get a handle on the next VC, use `segue.destinationViewController`.

Comment: Thanks dokun1.
This is also the way I do it in the moment. Is there any pattern with best practice rules how to work with this?

Comment: Where would I put logic for opening overlay elements like a side menu or error messages... there must be a pattern for that. I cant seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a particular pattern but a simple way to programmatically handle transitions between 2 `UIViewController` could be to have a separated manager whose job is just to push/present/whatever new controllers over current, and to pop/dismiss/whatever current controllers to old ones.

The way I usually do this is by having a class we can name `WorkflowManager`, which will handle all transitions. Associated with this manager, you declare a `WorkflowManagerComponent` protocol and implement it :

```
protocol WorkflowManagerComponent {
   var completionHandler: (hasCompleted:Bool,data:Any)->() {get set}
}
```

Make each UIViewController implement this, for example by calling `completionHandler(true,someData)` when the user taps a "next" button, or `completionHandler(false,nil)` when the user taps a "back" button.

Then in your workflow manager, you perform transitions to the next or previous `UIViewController` according to parameters sent in the `completionHandler`:

```
//init viewController1 ...
viewController1.completionHandler = onViewController1Completes

// ...
func onViewController1Completes(_ completed: Bool, data: Any) {
   if hasCompleted {
      //init viewController2 ...
      viewController2.data = data
      viewController2.completionHandler = onViewController2Completes

      //Push the new vc
      viewController1.navigationController.push(viewController2, animated: true)
    } else {
      //The vc1 was presented as a modal, dismiss it
      viewController1.dismiss()
    }

}
```

This way each `UIViewController` is separated from others, free off any transition logic.